# Move Test Plan from one Team project to another

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, mtm

We have TFS 2015.

Is there guidance or a mechanism to move Test plans from one Team Project to another Team Project in the same project collection? From poking in MTM, it seems like you can clone a Test Plan, but the dialog does not allow you to specify a different target Team Project for the cloned Test Plan.

Cloning the Test plans with associated Test Suites and Test Cases would also be acceptable if the items cannot physically be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Move a work item to another team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#move-a-work-item-to-another-team-project) is supported only from Team Services for now. Besides, **you can't move work items associated with test management.**

There has been a related uservoice for your requirement: *[Export test plan tree between projects and collections in MTM](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3634567-export-test-plan-tree-between-projects-and-collect#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)*

> We have enabled both Test Plan and Test Suite clone capabilities
>   within the product. See
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543843.aspx
>
> This allows you to clone test plans/test suites across projects within
>   a collection. For moving artifacts (including test artifacts) across
>   collections, you can use the “TFS Integration Platform toolkit”.
>
> *COMPLETED*  · Visual Studio Team (Product Team, Microsoft Visual Studio)

You could only do this in MTM, could also use `Tcm.exe` command to copy test suites.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2015 does not support moving work items between team projects, nor does it support cloning across team project boundaries. Your only option is to re-create the work item in the appropriate team project. There are various tools on the market that will create a new work item in the target team project and attempt to preserve most (but not all) of the history of the original.

VS Team Services does allow work items to be moved between team projects, however.

Comment: I figured I may run into this issue. Is there a way to clone the Test Plans, associated Test Suites and Test Cases into another team project? I could then delete the Test Plan in the original Team Project..